# MAMP 2 Multiple VirtualHosts with SSL

Tags: ssl, mamp, vhosts

I'm currently running into trouble configuring MAMP 2 to use SSL with multiple virtual hosts (it is working fine with one).  In my case, it will only provide an SSL connection for the first vhost listed in the https-ssl.conf file.

In my httpd-vhosts.conf file, I have several vhosts setup like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/sites/something/" 
    ServerName something.local 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/sites/else/" 
    ServerName else.local 
</VirtualHost>
```

In my https-ssl.conf file, I have several vhosts setup like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/sites/something"
    ServerName something.local:443
    ServerAdmin you@example.com
    ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/access_log"

    SSLEngine on

    #   SSL Cipher Suite:
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

    #   Server Certificate:
    SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server-dsa.crt"

    #   Server Private Key:
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server-dsa.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/Library/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    #   Per-Server Logging:
    CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/ssl_request_log" \
                  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/sites/else"
    ServerName else.local:443
    ServerAdmin you@example.com
    ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/access_log"


    ........add'l config deleted......
</VirtualHost>
```

It always works that first vhost listed in https-ssl.conf is provided SSL support, but not any listed after it (https://something.local would work, but not https://else.local)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one HTTPS host per IP - this a limit of HTTPS. Try `<VirtualHost ip.ad.dr.es:443>` for the different IPs to get a HTTPS host on each.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Is there any recourse for this when developing in a local environment?  I looked around a bit for how to setup multiple IPs for localhost on OSX (10.6) but couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: I am not an OSX guy, but I think it is System Settings -> Nettwork -> Add Interface -> Ethernet -> then static IP address

Comment: @EugenRieck TLS SNI, SAN certificates, and wildcard certificates are at least worth a mention, no?

Comment: @ShaneMadden The use of MAMP and the URL https://something.local made me believe, this is for a test setup, where adding a second IP would be the by far quickest resolution. Feel free to post a more through answer, I will certainly upvote it!

Answer (score 2):

The `.conf` file in the original question was *close* but not quite there...

In order for Apache to recognize different virual hosts over SSL you need to use *NameVirtualHost* and turn off "Strict SNI". Essentially, you need the following at the top of your `httpd-ssl.conf` file:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 443
Listen 443

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:443

# Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
# from non-SNI clients
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
```

and then make sure each of your vhost nodes are declared with the following tag:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

**Note : The browser you're using also needs to support SNI.**

All of this was taken from this page in the Apache docs:
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Thanks! this did the trick for me. Funny that `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck` isn't provided (or documented) in the default `httpd-ssl.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this either on `httpd-vhost.conf` if it is included or on `httpd.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

Thanks